# HTML5 Canvas drawing shapes with 3d edges

Tags: 3d, html5-canvas, effect

[image]

I'm trying to create buttons as shown in the image using HTML canvas.
I tried linear and radial gradient effects but I'm unable to  get the sharp edges as show in the image. The button should look like a 3D object.
There is a shining effect on top right (arrow)
bottom right edge effect for green button.

Following is the code I'm using for the blue circle

```
 var circle3 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.width()/2,
    y: stage.height()/2 ,
    radius: mainSmallCircleRadius,
    //fill: '#40A3D7',
    fillRadialGradientEndRadius: 260,
    fillRadialGradientColorStops: [0.225, 'rgba(130, 194, 238, 1.000)', 0.422, 'rgba(130, 194, 238, 1.000)',0.435, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.000)',0.451, 'rgba(254, 254, 254, 1.000)',0.494, 'rgba(254, 254, 254, 1.000)']
    //stroke: 'black',
    //strokeWidth: 0.5
  });
```

Comment: What library are you using? (What adds the Kinetic.Circle constructor?)

Comment: it seems like you are also using Kineticjs

Comment: 3D edges in 2D space are often simulated with extrusions. KineticJS (and it's new incarnation Konva) do not support extrusions. You might use a Shape object to get access to the native canvas context. From there you might pick up some techniques from this native canvas library that does extrusions rather well: http://jdan.github.io/isomer/